# Convert Nested List into CSV file without using External Packages

Tags: csv, tcl

I have a nested list, say {{1 2} {3 4} {5 6}}. I want to convert this to .csv file that has data like,

```
1 |3 |5
2 |4 |6
```

However, I cant at all use any packages like "csv". How do I go about doing this. I'm very new to TCL so I dont know how CSVs are manipulated without packages.

Comment: `foreach` and `join`.

Answer (score 1):

If you were trying to produce:

```
1 |2
3 |4
5 |6
```

then it would be quite simple.   No need for a csv package.

```
foreach list $nested_list {
    puts [join $list " |"]
}
```

However, your goal is to have the first csv row to use the first index of the nested list, the second csv row to use the second index, etc., I would recommend iterating by the index and using `lmap` in the loop.

```
set nested_list {{1 2} {3 4} {5 6}}

foreach i {0 1} {
    set items_at_i [lmap l $nested_list {lindex $l $i}]
    set csv_line   [join $items_at_i " |"]
    puts $csv_line
}
```

I'm not sure how using the tcllib csv package would package this any easier.  Is there some matrix rotation operation you're thinking of to change from rows to columns?

Comment: just wondering, what is the motivation for the question?  Why did you think it would be easier with the csv package?

Comment: Your account page says you work at Intel.   I do too.   Send me a company email to say hi.

Comment: you know adding tcl pkgs in our systems isnt easy and I'm just an Intern dabbling in TCL for the first time.

Comment: btw whats your name in Intel? Couldnt find you in email search.

Comment: Search by last name, but my full first name is Christopher.   
I'll show you how where the tcllib packages are.